# Wieso wirft man jemanden »hochkant« raus?

Tags: idiom

Wenn jemand irgendwo gehen muss und das »[grob, unnachsichtig](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/hochkant#Bedeutung2)« zu spüren bekommt, so fliegt sie hochkant, er wird hochkant hinausgeworfen.

Aber wieso »hochkant« oder auch »achtkantig«?

Menschen haben ja nicht so richtig Kanten wie z. B. Bücher (die man hochkant ins Regal stellt). Man kann zwar sagen, jemand sei kantig oder habe Ecken und Kanten, aber das passt nicht wirklich zu dieser Situation.

Comment: Quer passen die meisten nicht durch die Tür. :)

Comment: … aber horizontal, Kopf voran, fliegen die Leute besser.

Answer (score 4):

Laut [dieser Seite](http://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=jemanden%20achtkantig&bool=phrase&gawoe=an&suchspalte%5B%5D=rart_ou) soll es ein ursprünglich auf Bauholz bezogener Begriff sein und bedeuten, jemanden unverzüglich durch die Tür hinaus zu schicken, noch bevor er eine gemütliche Körperstellung (sitzende oder liegende Haltung) einnehmen kann. Demnach bedeutet "hochkantig" hier: aufgerichtet, aufrecht.

Comment: Wieso man gerade beim Rauswerfen, und eigentlich nur da, die Leute mit Bauholz vergleicht ist mir allerdings immer noch nicht klar.

Answer (score 1):

*Rauswerfen* ist ein Vorgang, bei dem etwas von innen nach außen geworfen wird. Dazu müssen Innen und Außen notgedrungen durch eine Öffnung verbunden sein, worunter man sich für gewöhnlich eine offene Tür vorstellen wird. Auch der Rauswurf durch ein Fenster ist denkbar.

Längliche Gegenstände (zu denen in diesem Zusammenhang auch unliebsame Personen gehören), kann man auf mehrere verschiedene Arten durch eine Tür werfen. Man stelle sich vor, man würde ein 180 cm langes Stück eines Baumstammes werfen wollen. Das ginge doch am besten, wenn man diesen Gegenstand so positioniert, dass dessen Längsachse annähernd mit der Richtung der beabsichtigen Flugbahn übereinstimmt. Das einfachste (und naheliegendste) wäre also, einen Menschen mit dem Kopf oder den Beinen voran rauszuwerfen.

Unmöglich ist es im Allgemeinen jedoch, einen Menschen quer durch eine Tür zu werfen. Das folgt aus den üblichen Abmessungen von Menschen und Türen. (Seltene Ausnahmen gibt es jedoch)

Bleibt noch die Möglichkeit, jemanden hochkant (also senkrecht stehend) rauszuwerfen. Bei Menschen entspricht das deren natürlicher Haltung im Stehen und auch im Gehen.

Allerdings ist es schwieriger und kraftraubender, einen Baumstamm (oder einen anderen Gegenstand mit mensch-ähnlichen Abmessungen) hochkant rauszuwerfen. Diese Energie bringt man freiwillig nur auf, wenn der Adrenalinspiegel erhöht ist, was z.B. dann der Fall ist, wenn man wütend ist.

Mit dem Wort »hochkant« wird also im übertragenen Sinn ausgedrückt, dass der Werfer wütend ist, und rein praktisch bedeutet es, dass sich der hinausgeworfene in aufrechter Position durch die Tür bewegt.

Comment: … Wie gesagt: Wieso man gerade beim Rauswerfen, und eigentlich nur da, die Leute mit (kantigen Dingen) vergleicht ist mir allerdings immer noch nicht klar. Und ein Baumstamm hat auch keine Kanten